# Dependency error when I build Entity Framework Core project

Tags: entity-framework

I just have added a new project .NET Console Core.

1-  Create a new Console Application(.NET Core) 
2-  Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer –Pre
3-  Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre

When I build I get the following build Error:
 **The dependency Ix-Async 1.2.5 does not support framework .NETCoreApp**

my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue answered [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc2-final).

Just add  `portable-net452+win81`  in the  `imports`  section of frameworks in the packages.json like so.

```
 "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    }
```

}

It worked for me.

Comment: thank you i have also found it in the announcing of the relase canditate 2

Comment: and if you are using the tools you have to to the same thing for the tools